# How to fire an action event in react 16.8?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just came in react after an year and before that I used to use `componentWillRecieveProps()` to call api(fire an action) just after getting updated props.

```
  componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.user !== this.props.user) {
      //Some api call using user prop
    }
  }
```

But now `componentWillRecieveProps` is replaced by `getDerivedStateFromProps` and there I cannot use `this` inside it. So how can I dispatch an event in newer react version or what is the best way?

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.user !== prevState.user) {
      this.fetchSetting();
      return { user: nextProps.user };
    }
    return null;
  }

  fetchSetting = async () => {
    const { fetchSetting } = this.props;
    const data = await fetchSetting();
  };
```

Comment: better way to use "new react" is skip classes entirely (unless you need error boundary) and just use hooks now.

Comment: @JoeLloyd Please provide an example with hooks.

Comment: https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/z1xzaupgpd-run-side-effect-when-a-prop-changes-whooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` which is a good replacement for `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Check the documentation here : [componentDidUpdate (React.Component)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

In you exemple you can do this :

```
static componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {
        this.fetchSetting();
        return { user: this.props.user };
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

But actually, if you really want to match the latest recommendations of React you shouldn't use classes but hooks which is aimed to be the new replacement. You can find more information about hooks on the page : [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

Comment: But I get previous props and state. I need current props and states.

Comment: In componentDidUpdate you can use the current props and states too.
Something like : `prevProps.status !== this.props.status` or `prevState.user !== this.state.user` will works.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can achieve this: you can use the new `useEffect` hook or you can use `componentDidUpdate` to compare the props manually and call a method that updates the state based on that.

The preferred way by the React team is the functional way (yea I know it's weird) using this:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

If you want to keep using the class-based way then you can use `componentDidUpdate`:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate